# MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection with the use of array object

Tags: mongodb

Ideally I want to have more documents with the same guildID in the guildList array (One user can join many guilds, One guildID can be stored by many user documents).
My Database already contain a document which has the same model as below and the same guildID, now that I cannot add another documents which contains same guildID.

```
{
  badges: [],
  _id: ObjectId("someID"),
  userID: 'someuserID',
  username: 'someusername',
  guildList: [
        {
          roleList: [],
          balance: 0,
          exp: 0,
          stars: 0,
          joinedTimestamp: ISODate("2020-11-19T03:15:21.241Z"),
          guildID: 'someguildID'
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Remove the unique constraint.

Comment: tried that but not work

Comment: Drop the unique index in mongodb